# Matplotlib opening 2 windows with plt.show()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

On my project, I'm using 2 figures with plt.show(), the first one, runs correctly, but the second one, creates 2 windows, 1 correctly named 'Figure 2',  and 1 with nothing on the screen, just the 'function bar', named 'Figure 1' (like the first figure). How can I create just the right window?

```
x = pd.DataFrame(maindf[missao_unica].value_counts())
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12), dpi=200)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = .5)
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.pie(x[missao_unica].tolist(), labels=x.index.tolist(),autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=False, startangle=90)
plt.title('Contagem(%)')
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
sns.heatmap(x,cmap='inferno_r')
plt.title('Contagem(Valor Absoluto)')
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.title('Coeficientes')
sns.countplot(maindf[missao_unica],dodge=None)
plt.savefig('Imagens\Missões.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have three figures in your code. Which one is creating problem? Be specific

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this if you use matplotlib objects directly instead of relying on the `pyplot` state machine. As an added bonus, you'll have more explicit and maintainable code.

The main thing here is to use `plt.subplots()` to set up all of your figures and axes ahead of time, and then explicitly operate on those objects and pass them directly to the seaborn functions that you want to use.

```
x = pd.DataFrame(maindf[missao_unica].value_counts())
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 12), dpi=200)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
axes[0].pie(x[missao_unica].tolist(), labels=x.index.tolist(),
            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90)
axes[0].set_title('Contagem(%)')

sns.heatmap(x, cmap='inferno_r', ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Contagem(Valor Absoluto)')

axes[2].set_title('Coeficientes')
sns.countplot(maindf[missao_unica], dodge=None, ax=axes[2])

# note the use raw strings for paths with back-slashes
fig.savefig(r'Imagens\Missões.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

close the plot window before generating new plot.

```
plt.close()
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12), dpi=200)
.... etc
```